# How to open the purple slime doors?

Tags: swords-of-ditto

I'm constantly blocked in some areas because some of their exit paths are blocked by purple slime doors.  On the map, the path is flagged with a "?".  I don't understand how to go through.

[image: Swords of Ditto, purple door]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution: you actually have to find a way around it, and once behind, there's a giant eye in the middle of the slime wall.  You can hit and destroy it.

[image: Swords of Ditto, slime door's eye]